# When update cart with more products that is added in inventory show low stock notification error in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**When update cart with more products that is added in inventory show low stock notification error then i don't want to update quantity and give error message in cart page**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution here is my solution

```
function my_plugin_update_cart_validation( $passed_validation, $cart_item_key, $values, $quantity ) {
global $woocommerce;
$cart_item = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
$product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
$variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
if($variation_id) 
{
    $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
    $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();

    if($quantity > $stock)
    {
        wc_clear_notices();
        $passed_validation = false;
        $nvErrormsg = 'Je kunt dit aantal niet aan je winkelmand toevoegen — we hebben er '.$stock.' op voorraad en je hebt er al '.$stock.' in je winkelmand.';
        wc_add_notice( __($nvErrormsg), 'error');
    }
}
return $passed_validation;
}add_filter('woocommerce_update_cart_validation','my_plugin_update_cart_validation', 10, 4 );
```